# Can brushing teeth to hard cause the gums to retract?

Tags: dentistry, gums

I started to notice that the gums around some of my teeth start to retract. Fortunately, this does not give me any discomforts and nothing looks like inflammation. But I suppose that ≈ 0.3mm - 0.5mm of exposed tooth isn't normal.

Can brushing my teeth to hard cause my gums to retract? Some info about me and my habits:

- I use a regular toothbrush. Not electric
- I often notice I'm brushing quite harsh and often have to pace myself
- Never had any dental problems in my life (I'm 24)
- The affected teeth are all on the 'corners'. I'm not a native English speaker so I hope you understand what I mean by this
- I smoke but never, apart from messing up my lungs, had any related health issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, according to the article bellow:

> But too much brushing, with bad technique, can cause other problems. "People think if they brush hard and thoroughly they are doing a good job, but you can wear away your gums and tooth surface. People think receding gums are a sign of gum disease, but it's often a sign of too much scrubbing."

https://www.theguardian.com/lifeandstyle/2011/feb/08/how-to-brush-your-teeth

Comment: Nice article! I will adjust the applied force when brushing. I also might switch to electric brushing

Comment: There is an element that should be added to this answere: On top of brushing lightly with the right techinique, it is important to use soft or ultra-soft bristles. Anything that is not removed with those bristles is better removed with metalic curettes at a dental office, which avoid rubbing off the gums.

Answer (score 0):

Bursh your teeth daily 3 times, but gently. For the front use up to down, from down to up motion, not left to right motion.

Also, you should use daily mouth wash liquide which kills the bacteria too and keeps your mouth very fresh

Do not eat hard food, when you become older you will lose your teeth early, eat always soft foods, fruits and avoid hard foot, sweets.

Comment: Do you have references to back up your claims?